# How to cycle and use a list as regex to search file

Tags: python-3.x

I'm currently doing a project that requires me to search a file for specific commands and print the line number. My issue arises from the large amount of commands that need to be searched for one by one.

```
bad_commands = ['Get-ComputerInfo', 'Invoke-Item']
transcript = open("transcripts/transcript.txt", "r")

for command in bad_commands:
     if re.search(command, transcript):
          print(command[], " has been found within the file")
     else:
          print("clean")
```

The file itself has `Get-ComputerInfo` within it so it should print out `Get-ComputerInfo has been found within the file`. Instead I am simply getting an error when running the script. The error is saying

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
     if re.search(command, transcript):

TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `transcript.read()` to get a (searchable) string of the file content.

The `open` function returns a file object as the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) says: 
`Open file and return a corresponding file object. If the file cannot be opened, an OSError is raised.`, 
 but `regex.search` expects to get a `string or bytes-like object` like the error says.

BTW, no need to use  `re.search` just do `if command in transcript.read():` as you're not really searching for regex strings.

Comment: this helps. The only issue is that it can only run once. once the code has been ran, i'd have to restart it as it doesnt seem to restart the list search. any suggestions?

Comment: Right, assign the string into a variable, e.g., `content = transcript.read()`, and use `content` for your tests.